# How to make plotly secondary x axis to work with rangeslider?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

### Context & problem:

I am trying to show the evolution of a value over time and some events that occured during the same period. One x-axis shows dates and I would like to get another x-axis, on top of the plot, that shows alternative tick-labels for dates *i.e.* events.

Here is a `ggplot` version of this plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
# here is a dummy dataset
df <- data.frame(
  timeaxis = seq.Date(from = as.Date.character("2020-01-01"), 
                      to = as.Date.character("2020-02-01"), 
                      by = "days"),
  avalue = runif(32)
)
# now I want to add a secondary axis to show events that occured during this time period
df_event <- data.frame(
  eventdate = as.Date.character(c("2020-01-05", "2020-01-17", "2020-01-20", "2020-01-25")),
  eventlabel = c("diner", "exam", "meeting", "payday")
)
# and the basic plot related to it
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = timeaxis, y = avalue)) +
  geom_line()
# I can add a new axis like so:
p <- p + scale_x_date(sec.axis = sec_axis(
  ~ .,
  breaks = df_event$eventdate,
  labels = df_event$eventlabel
))
print(p)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I need to use `plotly` for the awesome `rangeslider` that adds a very nice to use way to zoom in specific time periods.

Demo:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

plotly::ggplotly(p) %>% 
  plotly::layout(
    # as you can see the rangeslider is linked to xaxis, is it possible to link it to xaxis2?
    xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(visible = TRUE))
    )
  # note that using rangeslider() does not show the plot right...
```

[image]

As you can see, the second x-axis is not showing. Problem is that plotly does not have, yet, a good handling of secondary axis. First, if you use `ggplot2::scale_x_date(sec.axis = ggplot2::sec_axis()` to get a secondary x-axis, it is not transfered to the plotly plot by using `plotly::ggplotly()`. Second, if you manually define a secondary x-axis using `plotly` functions (as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52834636/10264278) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59638696/10264278), this axis does not change according to the `rangeslider` (I guess because the `rangeslider` is actually bound to `xaxis` and should de defined for `xaxis2` as well). Not to mention, I was not able to change the labels of the breaks to get the "events" displayed (even the example on

Demo:

```r
plotly::ggplotly(p) %>%
  # making an invisible trace
  plotly::add_lines(
    data = df_event,
    x = ~ eventdate,
    y = 0,
    color = I("transparent"),
    hoverinfo = "skip",
    showlegend = FALSE,
    xaxis = "x2"
  ) %>%
  plotly::layout(
    xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(visible = TRUE)),
    xaxis2 = list(overlaying = "x", side = "top")
  )
```

[image]

And with the actual event labels:

```r
plotly::ggplotly(p) %>%
  # making an invisible trace
  plotly::add_lines(
    data = df_event,
    x = ~ eventdate,
    y = 0,
    color = I("transparent"),
    hoverinfo = "skip",
    showlegend = FALSE,
    xaxis = "x2"
  ) %>%
  plotly::layout(
    xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(visible = TRUE)),
    xaxis2 = list(overlaying = "x", 
                  side = "top",
                  tickvals = df_event$eventdate,
                  ticktext = df_event$eventlabel)
  )
```

[image]

I tried to add `matches = "x", anchor = "x", scaleanchor = "x"` to `xaxis2` list but nothing changed.

### Question:

How to make a second axis in a plotly plot that reacts to "zoom" using `rangeslider`?

If you think there is a better way of achieving this, please go ahead! Any idea is very welcome, I am quite new to plotly and I certainly have overlooked its functionalities.

Comment: I like this solution. For me it allowed to preserve the tick marks set in `ggplot`. Typically I would use `plotly::rangeslider()` , which also required plotly to use `dynamicTicks`, that would eliminate any datetime scaling done by ggplot.