# Second y axis vanishing on ggplotly command with dynamick ticks =true, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have created the following dataframe and associated ggplot chart in R
First we import the libraries using R

```
 library(plotly)
 library(ggplot2)
```

Next we create the dataframe as follows

```
    dataframe_1<-data.frame("Month"=c(1:12))
    dataframe_1$Sales<-25*dataframe_1$Month
    dataframe_1$Fac1=dataframe_1$Sales/100
    dataframe_1$Month<-as.character(dataframe_1$Month)
```

Next we create a ggplot based bar chart combined with a line chart as folllows

```
   p<-ggplot(data = dataframe_1, mapping = aes(x = Month, y = Fac1))+geom_bar(data = dataframe_1, mapping = aes(x = Month, y = Sales/100, fill = "#82e600", text=paste0("Sales:", Sales)),stat="identity")+geom_line(mapping = aes(x = Month, y = Fac1, group = 1))+geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Month, y = Fac1, group = 1, text=paste0( "Factoid:", Fac1)),    inherit.aes = FALSE)+scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*100, name = "Sales"))+labs(fill =  "Sales")
```

When we render the plot p, we get a plot with two y axes. However, when we render the dynamicticks as true, the second y axis disappears

```
 ggplotly(p = p, tooltip = "text", dynamicTicks = TRUE)
```

I request someone to take a look and help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we must add a trace or plot_ly object onto the `ggplotly` object. [Adding second Y axis on ggplotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833214/adding-second-y-axis-on-ggplotly). This solution may work for some applications.