# How to make a stacked barplot with secondary y axis in R with ggplot and plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm working with the following dataframe:

```
data <- data.frame('Tipo_de_Parto' = c("Cesário", "Vaginal",
                                       "Cesário", "Vaginal",
                                       "Cesário", "Vaginal",
                                       "Cesário", "Vaginal",
                                       "Cesário", "Vaginal"),
                   'Ano_do_Nascimento' = c("2019", "2019",
                                       "2020", "2020",
                                       "2021", "2021",
                                       "2022", "2022",
                                       "2023", "2023"),
                   'perc' = c(34.1, 65.9,
                           32.0, 68.0,
                           0.0, 0.0,
                           36.6, 63.4,
                           39.2, 60.8),
                   'n' = c(723, 1395,
                           587, 1247,
                           0, 0,
                           545, 943,
                           439, 681))
```

I'm trying to plot something like this:

[image]

How can I plot it in R with ggplot and then transform it to an interactive plot with ggplotly? 'Tipo_de_Parto' filling the bars, 'n' as primary y axis and 'perc' as secondary y axis. 'perc' should be plotted as a line, but it needs to be filtered to only "Vaginal".

I'm doing it for a HTML file.

Comment: I don't think ggplot2 secondary axes will carry over to plotly with ggplotly, so you may need this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833214/adding-second-y-axis-on-ggplotly

Comment: Skip ggplot and put it straight into Plotly. Combine the two bar charts in one and add a line trace assigned to a secondary Y-axis.

https://plotly.com/r/graphing-multiple-chart-types/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry just realized this question was in R. You could create this directly with Plotly in Python. I'm sure it should be very similar in R.

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'Tipo_de_Parto': ['Cesário', 'Vaginal', 'Cesário', 'Vaginal', 'Cesário', 'Vaginal', 'Cesário', 'Vaginal', 'Cesário', 'Vaginal'], 
                   'Ano_do_Nascimento': [2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023], 
                   'perc': [0.341, 0.659, 0.32, 0.68, 0.0, 0.0, 0.366, 0.634, 0.392, 0.608], 
                   'n': [723, 1395, 587, 1247, 0, 0, 545, 943, 439, 681]})

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

for t in df['Tipo_de_Parto'].unique():
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Ano_do_Nascimento'][df['Tipo_de_Parto']==t],
                         y=df['n'][df['Tipo_de_Parto']==t],
                         name=t),
                  secondary_y=False)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Ano_do_Nascimento']df['Tipo_de_Parto']=='Vaginal'], 
                     y=df['perc'][df['Tipo_de_Parto']=='Vaginal'], 
                     name='% Normal',
                     mode='lines+markers+text',
                     
                     ),
           secondary_y=True)

fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(tickformat='.0%'))

fig.write_html('fig.html')
```

[image: fig]

Answer (score 2):

Building off the previous answer... still not sure this is exactly what you want, but it should get you close.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

data <- data.frame('Tipo_de_Parto' = c("Cesário", "Vaginal",
                                       "Cesário", "Vaginal",
                                       "Cesário", "Vaginal",
                                       "Cesário", "Vaginal",
                                       "Cesário", "Vaginal"),
                   'Ano_do_Nascimento' = c("2019", "2019",
                                           "2020", "2020",
                                           "2021", "2021",
                                           "2022", "2022",
                                           "2023", "2023"),
                   'perc' = c(34.1, 65.9,
                              32.0, 68.0,
                              0.0, 0.0,
                              36.6, 63.4,
                              39.2, 60.8),
                   'n' = c(723, 1395,
                           587, 1247,
                           0, 0,
                           545, 943,
                           439, 681)) %>%
  
  mutate(Ano_do_Nascimento = as.numeric(as.character(Ano_do_Nascimento)),
         perc = ifelse(Tipo_de_Parto == 'Vaginal', perc, NA)) # drop unwanted percentages here


# this is the factor we will use to scale the secondary y-axis
your_factor <- max(data$n) / 100


# plot bars
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Ano_do_Nascimento, y = n, fill = Tipo_de_Parto)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('Cesário' = 'blue4', 'Vaginal' = 'blue')) +
  
  # add percentages
  geom_point(aes(x = Ano_do_Nascimento, y = perc*your_factor),
             color = 'orange') +
  geom_line(aes(x = Ano_do_Nascimento, y = perc*your_factor),
             color = 'orange') +
  
  # add secondary y-axis
  scale_y_continuous("n", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./your_factor, name = "perc")) 

# calculate the range of the secondary y-axis
y2_range <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range / your_factor

# add the points to the plotly object
ggplotly(p) %>%
  
  # add the secondary axis back in
  add_trace(x=~Ano_do_Nascimento, y=~perc, yaxis="y2",
            data=data, showlegend=FALSE, inherit=FALSE, mode = "markers") %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right", title = "perc", range = y2_range))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could first create a `ggplot` with second axis. To have the points on the right scale you need a factor with your max values. After that you could add a second axis to your `ggplotly` object using `add_trace` with `yaxis="y2"` like this:

```r
your_factor <- max(data$n)/max(data$perc)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Ano_do_Nascimento, y = n, fill = Tipo_de_Parto)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_point(aes(x = Ano_do_Nascimento, y = perc*your_factor, color = Tipo_de_Parto)) +
  scale_y_continuous("n", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./your_factor, name = "perc")) 

ggplotly(p) |>
  add_trace(x=~Ano_do_Nascimento, y=~perc, colors=~Tipo_de_Parto, yaxis="y2", 
            data=data, showlegend=FALSE, inherit=FALSE, mode = "markers") %>%
  layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y", side = "right", title = "perc"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>